# The move from RNA to DNA and the necessity of reverse transcriptase

Tags: dna, rna

In [this piece](http://www.simonsfoundation.org/quanta/20140710-hints-of-lifes-start-found-in-a-giant-virus/#comment-142465) about giant viruses and the origin of life, in the context of the move from RNA world to DNA world, virologist Valerian Dolja states:

> In order to move from RNA to DNA, you need an enzyme called reverse transcriptase

Is this true though? Don't many DNA polymerases work with both, ssDNA and ssRNA templates, i.e. they function as reverse transcriptases although they're not "true" reverse transcriptases. So, in order to move from RNA to DNA, a reverse transcriptase was not a necessity like ribonucleotide reductase was for RNA to Uracil-DNA and thymidylate synthase was for Uracil-DNA to DNA?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. This flow of information is called the "[Central dogma of Molecular Biology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_dogma)". It basically describes the flow of information from DNA to RNA to proteins. Since a virus needs to amplify its genetic information before it can take over the infected cell and make only viral proteins and its genetic information, it has two possible options.

DNA viruses can use the cells replication and transcription machinery to make copies and express proteins. RNA viruses either have to use a reverse transcriptase to make DNA from its RNA genome to go on like the DNA viruses. Or they have to have a special, RNA-dependent (works only on RNA templates) RNA-polymerase (our RNA polymerase are all DNA-dependent and work only on DNA templates) to make more copies of their genome. Our DNA polymerases are dependent on DNA, the same is true for our RNA polymerases. So if the virus is not encoding (and actually bringing a few molecules with it in the virus) of the RT-polymerase or the special RNA-dependent RNA polymerase it will not be able to spread.

Using ribonucleotide reductases would theoretically be possible, but it is not the way nature went. And since a cell contains huge amounts of RNA, I doubt this would be a feasible way, as the enzyme would reduce all RNA. And later on the new viruses also needs new (not reduced RNA) to be packaged into new viruses. This would also be problematic.

Comment: You're writing about protein synthesis while my question concerns the transformation from RNA World to DNA World.

Comment: Sorry, but this is absolute not clear from your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry about that, although I don't really see how it's possible to confuse the discussion of RNA to U-DNA and U-DNA to DNA transformations with protein synthesis. Anyway, I clarified the original post. For those not familiar with U-DNA, here's an article.. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16164990

Comment: Could you give a reference for standard DNA polymerases using an RNA template?

Comment: @AlanBoyd Do you mean the original post by @5heikki?

Comment: @Chris yes, apologies for the ambiguity, OP asserts that standard DNA polymerase can use RNA template, but I would like to see the evidence for this.

Comment: @AlanBoyd Fine for me, I was just wondering. And yes, I would like to see evidence for it, too. Would be interesting.

Comment: Some top Google results for "DNA polymerase RNA template" (works even with Taq in vitro): https://norgenbiotek.com/display-resource.php?ID=82 http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC389454/ http://www.pnas.org/content/71/4/1035.full.pdf From last paper: "It is clear from the results presented that E. coli DNA polymerase I is able to synthesize extensive, well-matched
complementary DNA copies from a variety of natural RNAs, provided that the molar ratio of enzyme to RNA template is above a critical level."

Comment: The PNAS paper is about the Rous Sarkoma Virus, which is a retro virus. I would expect a RNA dependent DNA polymerase (aka reverse transkriptase) there. The other ones are about DNA polymerase I from E.coli, which is interesting. However this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7679988) (seems to be the original one on this topic) finds a much lower enzyme activity on RNA temples (between 0.1 - 0.4% of that on DNA templates) so the question is, how relevant this is. When there is DNA around this enzyme will most likely not use RNA as a template.

Comment: I imagine there wasn't much DNA around when RNA & protein to U-DNA & protein was happening (likely first in the viral realm) thanks to ribonucleotide reductase. The main point was that even present day DNA pols have at least some function in regard to polymerizing DNA from RNA templates and thus "true" reverse transcriptases were not a necessity to the transformation..

Comment: This argument seems to be very circular. In an RNA world there presumably wouldn't be any DNA polymerase at all - what we should be looking for is an enzyme that can make DNA using an RNA template - which is a reverse transcriptase. The key step in the evolution of such an enzyme would be switching from polymerising NTPs to polymerising dNTPs.

Comment: The fact that present day DNA pols can work with RNA templates in my opinion hints that their main substrate might have once been NTPs. However, then thanks to ribonucleotide reductase you got these fancy new dNTPs and it turned out that they worked as a substrate too. Maybe the higher affinity was there from the start or perhaps it was all about some other advantages (e.g. evading host defenses). So then, over the next 3.7 billion years or so DNA pols further evolved to make use of dNTPs more efficiently, losing their affinity to NTPs almost completely.

Comment: ..I think "true" reverse transcriptases are a much later evolutionary invention that happened after dsDNA genomes were already a thing. RTs were a new way to avoid them host defenses. Do any contemporary RTs work with U-DNA? I know arcaheal DNA pols generally don't..

Comment: ..As far as I know, no retroviral genome has ThyA or ThyX for de novo dTTP synthesis. Many dsDNA phages (Caudovirales) have such genes though and these branch near to the root of the relevant trees..

Comment: You may be interested in the paper here: 
http://www.jbc.org/content/275/33/25523.full.pdf . The authors find that single mutations in an RNA-directed RNA polymerase can reduce selectivity for an NTP substrate to the point that there is no significant preference for NTPs over dNTPs. However this comes at the cost of very much reduced rate of polymerisation.

Comment: also, do you think the OP is asking why viruses would ever use RNA instead of DNA?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is helpful in the context of moving from RNA to DNA world, but I do know that certain mutations to T7 RNA polymerase will allow that enzyme to use 2' deoxy nucleotides in addition to the normal ribonucleotides. These mutations were discovered by humans engineering the enzyme, but it's feasible that some transitional enzyme could have utilized both types of nucleotide. Then, those individuals with more DNA were favored because the DNA backbone is more stable than RNA backbone, eventually selecting for the modern DNA to RNA to Protein model.

Here is an article: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168165613002940